# Is there a personalization string for 'Business Unit' name?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Would be very useful for email templates title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The business unit *name*?  No.

But you do have the `%%memberid%%` [**personalization string**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/).  You can use that for dynamic content.